# Gitlab ci job is executing the wrong script

Tags: continuous-integration, cross-platform, gitlab-ci

I have a project in which we have Windows and Mac builds, so I'm trying to set up a GitLab CI pipeline where we build both versions. This is what my structure looks like right now:

```
.
|--src
+--jobs
|   +--macos
|   |   +--build_macos.yml
|   |   +--cmake_macos.yml
|   |   +--.cmake_macos.yml
|   +--windows
|   |   +--build_windows.yml
|   |   +--cmake_mingw-w64-x86-64.yml
|   |   +--.cmake_mingw-w64-x86-64.yml
|   +--stages.yml
+--.gitlab-ci.yml
```

And here's my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
include:
  - {local: '/jobs/stages.yml'}
  - {local: '/jobs/windows/build_windows.yml'}
  - {local: '/jobs/macos/build_macos.yml'}
```

My first job (build windows), instead of executing `.cmake_mingw-w64-x86-64.yml`, is executing `.cmake_macos` and I don't know why.

[image]

I'll add some of the other .yml files for more context.

`build_macos`:

```
before_script:
  - if [ -n "${CI}" ]; then
  -     conan user -p $ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN -r my_repo $ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
  - fi

include:
  - {local: "/jobs/macos/cmake_macos.yml"}
```

`build_windows`:

```
before_script:
  - if [ -n "${CI}" ]; then
  -     conan user -p $ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN -r my_repo $ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
  - fi

include:
  - {local: "/jobs/windows/cmake_mingw-w64-x86_64.yml"}
```

`cmake_mingw-w64-x86-64.yml`:

```
include:
- {local: "/jobs/windows/.cmake_mingw-w64-x86_64.yml"}

cmake:cmake-mingw-w64-x86_64:Release:
  stage: build-windows
  extends: .cmake
  variables:
    TOOLCHAIN: foo1/tools-builder/toolchain-mingw-foo:1.0
    BUILD_TYPE: Release

  tags:
    - docker
```

`cmake_macos`:

```
include:
- {local: "/jobs/macos/.cmake_macos.yml"}

cmake:cmake-macos:Release:
  stage: build-macos
  extends: .cmake
  variables:
    BUILD_TYPE: Release

  tags:
    - macos
```

I have tried changing the order of the `includes`, adding different tags, changing the file structure and nothing has worked. I don't understand why my `build windows` stage is using the script from `.cmake_macos`. Any help is appreciated, if needed I can provide other stuff

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. The `extends:` section in both `cmake_mingw-w64-x86-64.yml` and `cmake_macos.yml` only had `.cmake` instead of their full names. Changing it to their full/unique names fixed it.